# python 3.5: mailbox module can not decode iso-8859-1

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, encoding

I have a script to parse mailbox files and it works very well with python 2.7. The header is encoded as iso-8859-1 and so I could decode it easily like below:

```
import mailbox
logfile = '/var/mail/mailuser'
mbox = mailbox.mbox(logfile)
for msg in mbox:
      sender = unicode(msg ["From"].replace("'", '').replace('"', '') , 'ISO-8859-1')
```

Now I would like to run it with python3, as in python3 everything is by default unicode, I don't need to convert the text to unicode and I assume that the library should be able to handle the encodings. so my python3 version of code is like below:

```
import mailbox
logfile = '/var/mail/mailuser'
mbox = mailbox.mbox(logfile)
for msg in mbox:
  sender =msg ["From"].replace("'", '').replace('"', '')
```

but it throws an error:

```
File "read_smtp_3.py", line 147, in read_log_files
    for msg in mbox:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/mailbox.py", line 108, in itervalues
    value = self[key]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/mailbox.py", line 72, in __getitem__
    return self.get_message(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/mailbox.py", line 779, in get_message
    msg.set_from(from_line[5:].decode('ascii'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

As the library fails to decode the text, I am not sure how I can handle it?

Comment: Python uses `Unicode` to keep text in memory but it can get mails from server in `'ISO-8859-1'` or other encoding and you may have to convert `'ISO-8859-1'` (or other encoding) to unicode manually.

Comment: where should I do it manually? how? I am new to python3

Comment: did you try `(msg["From"].replace("'", '').replace('"', '')).encode('iso-8859-1')`?